# Glassfish deployment time

Tags: performance, deployment, glassfish, glassfish-3, ear

At the moment we use glassfish 3.1 as application server for our enterprise application. The application(s) are packed within an ear. The ear contains approximately

5 wars,
10 jars and
60 jars(ejb) .

The deployment of the ear takes more than 10 minutes. Is there any chance to tweak the deployment time of the application?

BTW: We splitted the ear already in smaller pieces. But in most cases we need the complete suite deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be running into this:
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17094

Download the latest GlassFish 3.1.2 build and see if it solves your problem:
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/3.1.2/promoted/glassfish-3.1.2-b23.zip

**Update**: GlassFish Server 3.1.2 has been released:
https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/glassfish_3_1_2_final

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reduce development time, there is two way for it for glassfish as much as I know.

First, you can deploy as a directory with `asadmin deploydir`. As a result of that you can change jsp files and method bodies, thanks to hot swap technology.

But the most elegant solution is using an alternative library in order to decrease the amount of deployments. There are a few alternative for this but you can use jrebel. It is quite stable. [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/current/) is used to reduce deployments and reloads class files on the fly by jvm its jvm agent. It has support for almost all well known frameworks.